# Toroidal implicit region looks weird

Tags: plotting, numerics, regions, computational-geometry

I have the following toroid surface:

```
tt = ParametricRegion[{Cos[u] (10 + 0.2 Sin[v]), 
    Sin[u] (10 + 0.2 Sin[v]), Cos[v]}, {{u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}}];
ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[tt[[1]]], {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 PlotRange -> {-11, 11}]
```

[image: parametric torus]

I want to build the solid region of the toroid (for the purposes of building a region difference and solving Laplace equation over that boundary)

I proceed by turning the torus

$\{Cos[u](R+r_f Sin[v]), Sin[u](R+r_f Sin[v]), Cos[v]\}$

into the implicit expression

$(\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-R}{r_f})^2 + z^2 \le 1$

```
ttSolid = 
 ImplicitRegion[((Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] - 10.0)/0.2)^2 + z^2 <= 1, {x, y, 
   z}]
RegionPlot3D[ttSolid]
```

But the implicit region doesn't look like a torus

[image: broken implicit torus]

Any idea what is the problem, and further, how to properly define a toroid region for NDSolve?

Comment: Could you copy your code into the Question instead of giving an image of it, so that others can copy the code directly into Mathematica?  Thanks.

Comment: It should be better now

Comment: Did you want an elliptic section  toroid?  This gives a thin circular section 0.2 radius                                                                 ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u] (10 + 0.2 Sin[v]), 
  Sin[u] (10 + 0.2 Sin[v]), 0.2 Cos[v]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have too few `PlotPoints`.  Try

```
RegionPlot3D[((Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] - 10.0)/0.2)^2 + z^2 <= 1,
 {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, -10, 10}, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]